# Why visual studio 2019 made everything bigger?

Tags: visual-studio

I am working on a web app in visual studio 2019. When I added a new version of the library I was working with everything suddenly went bigger! The menus, the backround etc...Any ideas why?

Comment: What version of what library did you add? You need to give SOME information on the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I might have the solution;

You can adjust the Zoom level in VS Code with the View > Appearance > Zoom commands. The zoom level increases or decreases by 20% each time a Zoom command is executed. View > Appearance > Zoom In (Ctrl+=) - increase the Zoom level.

Comment: OP is asking about Visual Studio, not VS Code.